# std::list fixed size

Tags: c++, stl, stdlist

How can I create `std::list` with a fixed element count?

Comment: The size should be fixed for all its lifetime? In that case, why do you use a list? Its advantages over arrays (and their wrappers, like `std::vector` and `std::array`) are mainly in terms of insertion/deletion of elements, asking for a fixed list is asking only for its disadvantages (more waste of memory, slow random access, ...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#include <list>

// list with 5 elements, using default constructor
const size_t fixedListSize(5);
std::list<int> mylist(fixedListSize);
```

If you want it to always have exactly 5 elements you'd have to wrap it in a facade class to prevent insertion and erasure.

If that is indeed what you want, you'd be better off using a different container instead of `list`, since as noted in other responses you would be hiding the most advantageous features of `list`.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Not really. Making the list const will disable insertion and deletion, but at the same time it will disable modification of the actual contents of the list.

Comment: Why the cast?  There's only one constructor that will match a call with a single integer type argument.

Comment: @David: if you wrap it in a facade class then it doesn't matter any more whether it's a `std::list` or what, so that's pretty irrelevant (one wouldn't use `std::list` then). The only way to restrict operations on `std::list` as such, keeping that type which presumably is what matters, is via `const`. Then elements can't be changed, but that's the cost of what the OP asks for.

Comment: @James - to make the intent explicit.  I know it would work without this but given it's a `list<int>` it seemed a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 14):

If you just want a fixed size container, maybe you are looking for [`std::tr1::array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983093.aspx). (Or just `std::array` for C++0x.)

If you don't insert or remove elements I don't think there is any advantage in using `std::list` instead of `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `std::list` constructor.

```
explicit list (size_type n, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Just specify at time of creation exact count of elements.

```
std::list<int> someList(20);
```

You could specify initial value for each element too.

```
std::list<int> someList(20, int(42));
```

[std::list::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/resize/) is the right solution too.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to ask you, why you want it to have a fixed number of elements and why use a list?

It could be that the user is implementing a cache with a limited number of elements and an LRU policy of removal. In that case a list is a good collection to use. Any time an element is accessed, you splice that element to the front of the list. If you need to insert a new elemenet (so the list gets full) you pop off the back of the list.

You can also maintain some kind of lookup for the elements but std::list is the best class to handle LRU.