# C++ fixed-size linked list

Tags: c++, list

**Non-duplicates:**

- [Which STL C++ container to use for a fixed size list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559730/which-stl-c-container-to-use-for-a-fixed-size-list) (Specific use case)
- [std::list fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907607/stdlist-fixed-size) (See below)

**Motives:**

Allocation happens once (in the constructor) and deallocation happens once (in the destructor).

O(1) insertion and removal of an element anywhere in the list *without needing to deal with the overhead of memory management*. This isn't possible with an array-based implementation.

Is there a straightforward approach for implementing this using the standard library? Is there an implementation of something like this in Boost?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What do you mean by allocation happens once and that deallocation happens just once?  What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: This isn't for a serious project. Having to allocate and deallocate memory whenever we insert or delete elements adds some overhead that could be avoided when we know an upper bound on the number of elements we want to hold in a list. I was just wondering if there were existing implementations of a list that allocated memory up front and didn't let it go until its end of life.

Comment: Check boost::intrusive::list and boost::intrusive::slist. Memory management is done automatically.

Comment: @yktula - This looks like another case of premature optimization. Unless we see that inserting and deleting objects from the list is the *main* activity of your program, it's not worth the trouble. Otherwise, having a faster allocation might perhaps make the program run 2% faster, and nobody will notice.

Comment: @Bo, yup. Like I said, this isn't for a serious project. I just wanted to know if something like this was available for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was first thinking when I read that was the approach to use a different allocator, i.e. one that pre-allocates a given number of elements to avoid the price of allocating. I'm not familiar with defining allocators though, but if you find out I'd be interested in the results.

Without that, here's a different approach. I saved myself the `template ...` stuff, but I guess you'll be able to do that yourself if you need.

```
typedef std::list<...> list_t;

struct fslist: private list_t
{
    // reuse some parts from the baseclass
    using list_t::iterator;
    using list_t::const_iterator;
    using list_t::begin;
    using list_t::end;
    using list_t::empty;
    using list_t::size;

    void reserve(size_t n)
    {
        size_t s = size();
        // TODO: Do what std::vector does when reserving less than the size.
        if(n < s)
            return;
        m_free_list.resize(n - s);
    }

    void push_back(element_type const& e)
    {
        reserve_one();
        m_free_list.front() = e;
        splice(end(), m_free_list, m_free_list.begin());
    }

    void erase(iterator it)
    {
        m_free_list.splice(m_free_list.begin(), *this, it);
    }

private:
    // make sure we have space for another element
    void reserve_one()
    {
        if(m_free_list.empty())
            throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    list_t m_free_list;
};
```

This is incomplete, but it should get you started. Also note that splice() is not made public, because moving elements from or to a different list would change both size and capacity.

Comment: "What I was first thinking when I read that was the approach to use a different allocator" :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do it would be to have 2 data structures. An array/vector which is fixed sized and is used for "allocation". You simply grab an element from the array to create a node and insert it into your list. Something like this seems to meet you requirements:

```
struct node {
    node *prev;
    node *next;
    int value;
};

node storage[N];
node *storage_ptr = storage;
```

then to create a new node:

```
if(node == &[storage + N]) {
    /* out of space */
}

node *new_node = *storage_ptr++;
// insert new_node into linked list
```

This is fixed size, allocated all at once, and when `storage` goes out of scope, the nodes will be destroyed with it.

As for efficiently removing items from the list, it is doable, but slightly more complex. I would have a secondary linked list for "removed" nodes. When you remove a `node` from the main list, insert it at the end/beginning of the "deleted" list.

When allocating, check the deleted list first before going to the `storage` array. If it's `NULL` use `storage`, otherwise, pluck it off the list.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a template for this called rigid_list.
It's far from complete but it's a start:

https://github.com/eltomito/rigid_list

(motivated by Ulrich Eckhardt's answer)